# "Date" column cannot be read by df_dates = df.loc[:,'Date'] (Data coming from yahoo Fin)

Tags: python, pandas, date, yahoo-finance

I am currently getting data from Yahoo Finance and for my code purpose i need to loc Date and Open variables.

```
df_dates = df.loc[:,'Date'] # Get all of the rows from the Date column
df_open = df.loc[:,'Open'] #Get all of the rows from the Open column
```

However, as I understand Date doesn't seem like a Column but we can see there is Column Called "Date"

I am pulling update from yahoo like this;

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AMD", start ='2019-10-01')
```

and after i execute ;

```
df_dates = df.loc[:,'Date'] # Get all of the rows from the Date column
df_open = df.loc[:,'Open'] #Get all of the rows from the Open column
```

This is the error I get.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'
```

How can I locate the column "Date"?

Best,

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `pandas` & `date`).

Comment: Don't you just need to call `df_dates = df['Dates']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AMD", start ='2019-10-01')
```

**Checking the columns and index:**

```
df.columns
```

**Output:**

```
Index(['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], dtype='object')

df.index
```

**Output**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03', '2019-10-04',
               '2019-10-07', '2019-10-08', '2019-10-09', '2019-10-10',
               '2019-10-11', '2019-10-14', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-16',
               '2019-10-17', '2019-10-18', '2019-10-21', '2019-10-22',
               '2019-10-23', '2019-10-24', '2019-10-25', '2019-10-28',
               '2019-10-29', '2019-10-30', '2019-10-31', '2019-11-01',
               '2019-11-04', '2019-11-05', '2019-11-06', '2019-11-07',
               '2019-11-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

As you can see `Date` belongs to the index and therefore you cannot select it by its label. Using reset_index directly on the read data frame **may not be convenient because the rest of the `columns` no longer have the `Date` index**. Use [`Index.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) and then [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df_Open=df[['Open']] #this returns a DataFrame, you don't need loc
df_dates=df.index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_dates)

         Date
0  2019-10-01
1  2019-10-02
2  2019-10-03
3  2019-10-04
4  2019-10-07
5  2019-10-08
6  2019-10-09
7  2019-10-10
8  2019-10-11
9  2019-10-14
10 2019-10-15
11 2019-10-16
12 2019-10-17
13 2019-10-18
14 2019-10-21
15 2019-10-22
16 2019-10-23
17 2019-10-24
18 2019-10-25
19 2019-10-28
20 2019-10-29
21 2019-10-30
22 2019-10-31
23 2019-11-01
24 2019-11-04
25 2019-11-05
26 2019-11-06
27 2019-11-07
28 2019-11-08
```

Comment: Wow this community is amazing i didn't expect to answer that fast... Thank you

Code worked perfectly however in the next steps i received another error for my next step of code;

#Create the independent data set 'X' as dates
for date in df_dates:
  dates.append( [int(date.split('-')[2])] )
  
#Create the dependent data set 'y' as prices
for open_price in df_open:
  prices.append(float(open_price))



The error is;

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: consult: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html

Comment: Anyway you can open another question if you have doubts and look in other questions of the forum. Surely you can find what you need :)

Comment: You are welcome, with split what you intend is to catch only the day right? I think you need = `df_dates['Date'] = pd.to_datetime (df_dates['Date'])`, then `df_dates ['Date'].dt.month` or `.day` or `.year`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you guys are very helpful

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Date` is the index of the dataframe and not in a column. Access it using `df.index`.

Also, you can do a `df.reset_index()` and then access it. 
So with your code:

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AMD", start ='2019-10-01').reset_index()

df_dates = df.loc[:,'Date'] # Get all of the rows from the Date column
df_open = df.loc[:,'Open'] #Get all of the rows from the Open column
```